# Convert timestamp to date using Angular 2 pipes

Tags: angular, typescript, timestamp, angular-pipe

I'm trying to convert a `timestamp` to a date format using Angular pipes. I wrote this in the HTML template:

```
{{myTimestamp | date}}
```

Where `myTimestamp` is of type number.

I get unexpected results, for example, the timestamp `1468251287` (Which matches Nov 7, 2016) is displayed as `Jan 18, 1970`.

I would like to know how I can fix this issue.

Comment: When you multiple the timestamp by **1000**, it will show the correct date.

Comment: Ok, that works fine, but why is that?

Comment: Angular (javascript) uses **milliseconds** instead of **seconds** @Kikus

Answer (score 146, accepted):

As mentioned by @Perry you will need to provide the date in milliseconds.  From the Angular 2 reference for [date](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) we have:

> expression is a date object or a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch)
>   or an ISO string

So it can be simply be:

```
{{load.loadDate * 1000 | date}}
```

Answer (score 16):

I used:

```
<div>{{score.timestamp | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</div>
```

More info in https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: this works for Date objects. With epoch time, the other answer can be used to convert to valid time objects

Comment: this works for Date objects. With epoch time, the other answer can be used to convert to valid time objects

Answer (score 0):

So if your looking to change `timestamp` to specific date then try this:

`Date(user.dob).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')`