# Angular 11: formatted date is set always to 1970

Tags: angular, angular11

After upgrading to Angular 11 the [date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) does not any longer display properly. If I try

```
 date to display {{1610038272|date:"medium"}} === Jan 07, 2021, 16:51:12
```

but instead it displays

```
 Jan 19, 1970, 16:13:58
```

Is there any breaking change which prevents a proper conversion? Or do I need to set something additonally?

Comment: The `valueOf()` Jan 07, 2021, 16:51:12 is 1595350272321. 1610038272 is way in the past and falls back to 1970

Comment: most likely depending on the time zone. But anyway nothing like 1970!!!

Comment: What does your console say when you `console.log(new Date(1610038272));`?

Comment: strange ... it says `1970-01-19T15:13:58.272Z` so obviously the JS is to be blamed. What does it say on your console? `new Date(1610038272)`

Comment: Same thing (just different time zone). That's why I asked you to check your console. It has nothing to do with Angular. Why are you surprised if this is the date corresponding to the numeric value?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569832/convert-timestamp-to-date-using-angular-2-pipes?

Comment: Seems that starting with version 2 of Angular, you have to provide the date as milliseconds since UTC epoch, 1610038272 is the value in seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to provide the the date in milliseconds

[Convert timestamp to date using Angular 2 pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569832/convert-timestamp-to-date-using-angular-2-pipes)

`{{ 1610038272 * 1000 | date: 'medium' }}`

Comment: Thanx for the hint. Somehow the Spring backend conversion now serializes the `Date` incorrectly. Don't know why but I take now the `toEpochMilli` and the conversions succeeds. Thx for the direction!

Comment: Yep, same thing happened with me. We had recently migrated from Date to LocalDateTime, and we had to write a custom jackson serializer for Date to maintain backwards compatibility. Changing getEpochSeconds to toEpochMilli worked!